# Testing "complex" operations : Risk-like board game deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd

I develop a Risk-like game with Ruby on Rails and I have to develop a procedure to dispatch (randomly) territories among characters and to dispatch (randomly) characters' units to their territories.

The game has 42 territories for 5 characters. 3 characters receive 8 territories and 2 characters receive 9 territories. Each character has a pool of 25 units (27 for ones having 9 territories) to dispatch among allocated territories. Each territory must end up with at least 1 unit.

My models are the following. I'm okay to change it if needed.

- User ;
- Game ;
- Area ;
- Character, binding a user to a game, holding the remaining units to deploy ;
- Territory, link a character to an area, holding the number of units on that area.

Now here are my thoughts.

- I should separate the two operations (territories dispatch and units dispatch), even if it less performant ;
- To test more easily, the output state should be the same with a same input : the random part should come from outside.

What assertions would you write for such a scenario?
I use the default Rails 3 testing stack : Test::Unit and fixtures.

[The code is available on GiitHub](https://github.com/Sephi-Chan/conquest-on-rails-reboot).

Thanks!

Comment: Never played Risk but I wonder to what extent initial random positionning could be coded as some recursive method. If it could, testing would be easy: with fixtures representing the step before last position is set (N-1), the result of your positionning method would belong to a limited set. You have a spec here.

Answer (score 1):

The assertions you need seem pretty simple :

- The game has 42 territories
- for 5 characters.
- 3 characters receive 8 territories and 2 characters receive 9 territories.
- Each character has a pool of 25 units

and so forth...

> My models are the following. I'm okay to change it if needed.
>
> - User ;
> - Game ;
> - Area ;
> - Character, binding a user to a game, holding the remaining units to deploy ;
> - Territory, link a character to an area, holding the number of units on that area.
>
> Now here are my thoughts.
>
> - I should separate the two operations (territories dispatch and units dispatch), even if it less performant ;
> - To test more easily, the output state should be the same with a same input : the random part should come from outside.

As a side note, I think you've gone more than far enough in upfront design here. TDD is supposed to make the design of your code emerge and evolve, so while you could stick to these pre-established rules at first, you shouldn't be afraid to make changes to them or even wipe them out altogether as you write your tests.

The best way to test drive your implementation is to get going with a first test, then another... and progressively discover what the best design seems to be, not try to build a perfect model from the start.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't some kind of PlayerSelector something useful?

Maybe a method Player selectPlayer() or Player ID.
Then you can do the selection deterministic with some kind of CyclicSelector stub...
First country you select goes to player1, second to player 2, 3,1,2,3 etc.